# Passing arguments dynamically to an exe from an application

Tags: c++

I am writing a C++ application which calls an executable. I need to pass arguments to that executable using my C++ application, dynamically.

If the executable displays a message "Enter the input", C++ application should pass input file name.
If the executable displays a message "Press R to exit", C++ application should press R.

How can i accomplish this task of dynamically passing arguments to exe based on the message displayed.

Comment: This seems to depend on the platform in question; do you use Windows? Is "the executable" to be called a console application?

Comment: Hi @Codor
I use windows and the executable is a console application.

Comment: Removed "arguments-passing" because that doesn't apply. Arguments to a process are passed on the command line, and end up in `argv[]` in the child process. You're describing standard input.

Answer (score 0):

Create the child process with Redirected Input and Output [hStdInput , hStdOutput] by specifying in the [STARTUPINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) .

`HANDLE hStdInput - Standard input handle of the child process.
 HANDLE hStdOutput - Standard output handle of the child process.`

Read the output handle pipe of the child process.

This [msdn article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190351) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28VS.85%29.aspx) would be helpfull.